# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject`

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I'm new with Kotlin and I'm trying to use it to make an app with Spring boot.I have just done the entities and anything else yet because I want to know if the app runs but I tried running it and it gives me the following exception "Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject"

Career Entity:

```
package ar.com.school.management.models.entity

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import jakarta.persistence.*
@Entity
data class Career(@Id
              @GeneratedValue(strategy = 
              GenerationType.IDENTITY)
              @Column(name = "career_id")
              var id: Long?,

              var name: String?,

              @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
              @JoinTable(name = "career_subject",
                  joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "career_id", referencedColumnName = "career_id")],
                  inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "subject_id")])
              @JsonIgnoreProperties("subjectCareers")
              var subjects: List<Subject>? = mutableListOf(),

              @OneToMany(mappedBy = "career")
              var students: List<Student>? = mutableListOf(),

              @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
              @JoinTable(name = "career_teacher",
                  joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "career_id", referencedColumnName = "career_id")],
                  inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "teacher_id")])
              @JsonIgnoreProperties("careers")
              var teachers: List<Teacher>? = mutableListOf()) {
constructor(): this(null,null,null, null, null)
}
```

Student Entity:

```
package ar.com.school.management.models.entity

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import jakarta.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Student(@Id
                   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                   @Column(name = "student_id")
                   var id: Long?,

                   @Column(name = "social_security_number")
                   val socialSecurityNumber: Int?,

                   var name: String?,
                   var surname: String?,
                   var address: String? ,
                   var age: Int?,

                   @ManyToOne
                   @JoinColumn(name = "career_id")
                   var career: Career?,

                   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("students")
                   var subjects: List<Subject>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @Column(name = "finished_subjects")
                   var finishedSubjects: List<Subject>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @Column(name = "subjects_marks")
                   var subjectsMarks: Map<Subject, Double>? = mutableMapOf()) {
    constructor(): this(null,null,null,null,null,
        null,null, null,null,null)
}
```

Subject Entity:

```
package ar.com.school.management.models.entity

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import jakarta.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Subject(@Id
                   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                   @Column(name = "subject_id")
                   var id: Long?,

                   var name: String?,

                   @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                   @JoinTable(name = "subject_student",
                       joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "subject_id")],
                       inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id")])
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("subjects")
                   var students: List<Student>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("subjects")
                   @Column(name = "careers")
                   var subjectCareers: List<Career>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                   @JoinTable(name = "subject_teacher",
                       joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", referencedColumnName = "subject_id")],
                       inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id", referencedColumnName = "teacher_id")])
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("subjects")
                   var subjectTeachers: List<Teacher>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @Column(name = "correlative_subjects")
                   @ElementCollection
                   var correlativeSubjects: List<String>? = mutableListOf()) {
    constructor(): this(null, null, null, null, null, null)
}
```

Teacher Entity:

```
package ar.com.school.management.models.entity

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties
import jakarta.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Teacher(@Id
                   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                   @Column(name = "teacher_id")
                   var id: Long?,

                   @Column(name = "social_security_number")
                   val socialSecurityNumber: Int?,

                   var name: String?,
                   var surname: String?,
                   var address: String? ,
                   var age: Int?,

                   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjectTeachers")
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("subjectTeachers")
                   var subjects: List<Subject>? = mutableListOf(),

                   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teachers")
                   @JsonIgnoreProperties("teachers")
                   var careers: List<Career>? = mutableListOf())             {

    constructor(): this(null,null,null,null,null,null,null, null)
}
```

Track:

```
2023-01-09T00:56:17.957-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] ar.com.school.management.ApplicationKt   : Starting ApplicationKt using Java 17.0.5 with PID 43310 (/home/beniko/IdeaProjects/-Spring-boot-Kotlin-School-Management/build/classes/kotlin/main started by beniko in /home/beniko/IdeaProjects/-Spring-boot-Kotlin-School-Management)
2023-01-09T00:56:17.960-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] ar.com.school.management.ApplicationKt   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-09T00:56:17.998-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-09T00:56:17.999-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-09T00:56:18.379-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-09T00:56:18.389-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-09T00:56:18.678-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-09T00:56:18.684-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-09T00:56:18.684-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-01-09T00:56:18.715-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-09T00:56:18.716-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 716 ms
2023-01-09T00:56:18.797-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-09T00:56:18.902-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@361fd59
2023-01-09T00:56:18.903-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-09T00:56:18.927-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-09T00:56:18.949-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-09T00:56:19.026-03:00  WARN 43310 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-01-09T00:56:19.099-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-01-09T00:56:19.206-03:00 ERROR 43310 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject`
2023-01-09T00:56:19.206-03:00  WARN 43310 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject`
2023-01-09T00:56:19.207-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-01-09T00:56:19.267-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-01-09T00:56:19.269-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-09T00:56:19.277-03:00  INFO 43310 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-09T00:56:19.286-03:00 ERROR 43310 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject`
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at ar.com.school.management.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `ar.com.school.management.models.entity.Subject`
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.BasicCollectionJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(BasicCollectionJavaType.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1766) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it is since the configuration is missing, but it might be two things:
- Don't use data class as it's not always compatible, use regular classes instead for JPA.
- Use allopen plugin for kotlin & JPA

Comment: But data classes are incompatible with data classes.
I'll try to use class instead of data classes but the bad thing is that I can't autogenerate getters, setters, toString, equals automatically

Comment: This is Kotlin; you don't need to worry about getters and setters. (They're generated automatically if you don't give them explicitly; either way, calling them looks like a normal field access. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html).) Yes, you'll probably need to override `toString()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()`, though with Kotlin syntax ([expression bodies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions), [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#string-templates)) those can be very concise.